# What is the equivalent to beforeNuxtRender in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 2 it was in the plugin context:

```
export default function somePlugin(({ beforeNuxtRender }) => {
  beforeNuxtRender(() => {})
})
```

In Nuxt 3 we have hooks, but there doesn't seem to be the right hook for that?

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxt) => {
  nuxt.hook("???")
})
```

Comment: Please provide some more code of what you want to achieve with that hook. Maybe it can be achieved by a different hook.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass data from server-side to client-side you should use `useState`

```
// plugins/foo.server.ts
export const useFoo = () => useState('foo', () => 'bar')

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const foo = useFoo();
})
```

```
// useFoo composable 
const foo = useState('foo');

console.log(foo.value) // 'bar'
```

more in docs https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/state-management